# Dotnet 6 application on docker can't access IBM Mq queue manager

Tags: .net, .net-core, ibm-mq

I have a dotnet 6 application that works well from local machine in terms of connecting with MQ series queue manager. But when I host the app within linux docker container, the application can't establish connectivity with queue manager and fails with error :

MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE Reason:2538

Are there any suggestions or pointers ?

I wanted to disable firewall within container, but iptables command doesn't seem to be working within linux docker container with dotnet 6 image.

Comment: Can you telnet from the docker to the queue manager and port?

Comment: telnet is not working either....I tried apt-get, sudo - none of commands is recognized

Comment: Sounds like you have a docker issue not a MQ issue.  Once you have the network issue fixed you should come back if you do have MQ issues.

Comment: Where is the queue manager running? Is that also in a container? If so is the queue manager container in the same docker network as the app container?

Comment: Comment from Techie1723: joshmc and @chughts  -Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Queue manager is on premise and not on container.
I managed to  resolve my issue by adding a hosts file entry in docker container. The hostname of queue manager client connection tab file was not resolving to a valid IP address. Hence I added a mapping in etc/hosts which resolved the problem.